# Strict vs non-strict: Which instance of a named variable gets used?

Tags: perl, function

I am trying to find the problem and propose a solution for the following Perl code.

A file without `strict` nor `warnings` on it has a function that uses a `$variable` without declaring it. So that variable is global to the file and the changes for that variable in this specific function are used outside of it (since it is global for the file).

Due to a recent update, this `old_file` now `requires` a modified version of itself (`new_file`) in which the same function is defined. But this new version has `strict` and `warnings`, so the same variable is defined, but this time as 'my' in the new function, and is returned in the end.

The tricky thing is that the code in the `old_file` did not change so it still expects the variable to be changed as its own global variable.

Since I don't know Perl well enough to be able to determine which version of this function is used (and since I can't test it, due to IT restrictions) I need an explanation of the behavior, possibly a link to a good paper about that topic.

**Code:** (I think the problem is in the variable `LISTEREPONSE` from the function `start_handler`.)

old_file:

```
use XML::Parser;
my $parser = new XML::Parser( ErrorContext => 2 );
$parser->setHandlers(
    Start => \&start_handler,
    End   => \&end_handler,
    Char  => \&char_handler
);
$parser->parse(<$remote>);

close $remote;
...
sub start_handler {
    my $expat   = shift;
    my $element = shift;
    print;

    while (@_) {
        my $att = shift;
        my $val = shift;
        $LISTEREPONSE .= "$att=$val&";
    }
}
```

new_file:

```
sub start_handler {
    my $expat   = shift;
    my $element = shift;
    print;
    my $LISTEREPONSE;

    while (@_) {
        my $att = shift;
        my $val = shift;
        $LISTEREPONSE .= "$att=$val&";
    }
    return $LISTEREPONSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In strict mode, if you need $LISTEREPONSE become a global variable in package(file) scope.

Just declare (my $LISTEREPONSE;) in the beginning of file (after use).

In second case, $LISTEREPONSE is declare in sub, it's lexical scope and only available in sub.

```
my $LISTEREPONSE;
# ...
sub some_sub {
    $LISTEREPONSE .= $some_stuff;
}
```

Comment: I indeed got that point, what i wanted to know is which of the 2 sub's code will be excuted i guess it is the one of the latest require. I am only guessing and couldnt find the specific document on it tough it might be very simple... but i think the latest sub will just take the place on one which would have had the same name....

Comment: It's seems that the code iteration the whole xml document, and join some attr/values together to a single string. The traditional way it's declare a global variable, and join each in subs call of xml processing.

Comment: Don't care the names, variables declare using "my" in "{" and "}" is's local and won't affect each other. See perlvar http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: My question was more about which function will be called since there are 2 with the same name. I guess it will be the last one that is loaded by perl therefore the one from the last require.

Comment: Don't name two function with same name. You can use "print 'call func1';" and "print 'call func2';" instead of "print;" in two functions.